# Adding a date time field value within a node programmatically

Tags: nodes

```
 [field_download_time] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => 2012-11-27 09:38:00
                                [timezone] => America/Phoenix
                                [timezone_db] => America/Phoenix
                                [date_type] => datetime
                            )

                    )

            )
```

What I see for a field_download_time is given above..
I am adding nodes programmatically so the code for following field is as given below

```
 $download_node->field_download_time[]['value'] = date('m-d-Y H:i', REQUEST_TIME);//--?
```

I don't get an error on running the above code but **the value of current date** is not displayed

But When I run the following code given below I get an error 
**THE ERROR** :
 **Actually the code is such that when u go to the link it downloads a file .Basically the error is that  file is not downloaded.**

```
  $download_node->field_download_time['und'][]['value'] = date('m-d-Y H:i', REQUEST_TIME);//--?
```

Comment: Be sure to call `node_save()` after you've changed the value of the field. Until then it won't appear.

Comment: yes I have added node_save() but the value is not being displayed..

Comment: try this `$download_node->field_download_time['und'][0]['value'] = date('m-d-Y H:i', REQUEST_TIME);`. After that add `node_save($download_node);`.

Comment: Yes I have done the same thing but it gives error when checked the node i got an empty array for field_download_time .also field_download_time is multiple value field so `field_download_time['und'][]['value']`

Comment: please edit the question and add the error you're getting. Are you sure you've placed the key `[0]` between `['und']` and `['value']`?

Comment: but that field is having  unlimited value..so if I have multiple time field time it would only consider the first field so I can't use field_download_time['und'][0]['value']

Comment: @Ajit S , Actually the code is such that when u go to the link it downloads a file .Basically the error is that I file is not downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => 2012-11-27 09:38:00
                                [timezone] => America/Phoenix
                                [timezone_db] => America/Phoenix
                                [date_type] => datetime
                            )
```

As seen above,
the error was occuring due to improper date format So when I changed the date format to  **`date(Y-m-d\TH:i:s, REQUEST_TIME);`**
the `$download_node->field_download_time['und'][]['value']` did not gave any error .

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$mynode->field_download_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "2012-11-27";
$mynode->field_download_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['timezone'] = "America/Phoenix";
$mynode->field_download_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['timezone_db'] = "America/Phoenix";
$mynode->field_download_time[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['date_type'] = "datetime";
```

Comment: yes this will also work.